# "database or disk is full" error when joining two tables

Tags: python, sqlite

With [California Traffic Collision Data from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/alexgude/california-traffic-collision-data-from-switrs/code) I want to join two tables based on case id but selecting only rows that have a collision date of > 2020:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(".../switrs.sqlite")

df_sqllite = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM parties JOIN collisions USING (case_id) WHERE collision_date >= "2020-01-01"', con)
```

I get this error:

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM parties JOIN collisions USING (case_id) WHERE collision_date >= "2020-01-01"': database or disk is full

How to solve this?

Comment: _database or disk is full_ Have you checked to see if your disk is... full?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM parties as p JOIN collisions as c USING c.case_id WHERE c.collision_date >= "2020-01-01

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).